How to know what are the cables slightly below insulated powerlines in Norway?
Recently I discovered that in some cases, power lines in Norway have seemingly 4 cables. Ie this one:

From a slightly different angle:

(Source of these images.)
On Bing Streetside as well:

Google Steet View:

Coordinates of these images: 58.72094N, 5.68797E. I am interested in the function of the cable slightly below the 3 power cables. The power cables have those insulating discs on them (3 on one side, 2 on the other), the cable slighlty below does not. The powerline in question is on OpenStreetMap, with the cables value set to 3 - this is a power related tag, reinforcing my suspicion that the cable slightly below the other ones is not a power cable.
Recently, I had a similar question regarding a cable in France - that cable is on its own, not on the same poles as 3 powerlines. In addition to this, here I don't see any 'coil of "cable" hanging on the pole' - which was part of the justification why the cable in France is a telecom cable. Maybe in Norway they cut their cables more precisely, so they don't need to coil it. My best guess is that the fourth cable is a cable related to communication, but still, I'm unsure.
I saw this at other locations as well, but this one was particularly good for having good photo coverage.
How can I deduce what the 4th cable is?

In the US, that would likely be the combined neutral/ground conductor. My guess is that it is the same in Norway. It is there for multiple reasons. One is to help rapidly dissipate the effect of electrical strikes. This wire is therefore periodically grounded. A second reason, in the US at least, is to carry imbalance current. The algebraic sum of the currents between the substation and the distribution transformers must be \$0\$. In the US, there are many distribution transformers whose primary terminals are connected to one phase and neutral/ground. Under ideal conditions, the currents in all the phase wires will balance, and no current will flow in neutral/ground. But in practice, that is never the case, and the neutral/ground wire carries the imbalance current. (In the US, a portion of this imbalance current is also carried through the physical ground, ie. the soil). This inevitably happens because the substation is grounded via a network of grounding conductors, and the neutral/ground wire is also grounded. As a result the physical ground forms a parallel path for return current to the neutral ground cable.
